# Uber API "POST /requests/estimate" response POST "code":"unauthorized"

Tags: api, uber-api

i'll try to get data by following API calling:

**Uber API -- POST /requests/estimate**

```
curl -X POST \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer JA.VUNmGAAAAAAAEgASAAAABwAIAAwAAAAAAAAAEgAAAAAAAAG8AAAAFAAAAAAADgAQAAQAAAAIAAwAAAAOAAAAkAAAABwAAAAEAAAAEAAAAHK_p1D73ZBrTyH5MuBCGAhsAAAA28z3l42QLSOiQE_6m1J30O4ZQjwpDR_rVf5o41ONOluUZohTYhXEhHNBCLkDO0mXJV39hE2RkcsIRm9ICi_UMVGESeHsQ_uRsX_yD1EDoUbcdHa0Yhf8XGOJkFz1-IB5x9Ivq6SxHpmREeExDAAAAGRcztTG8GDUTlDYpSQAAABiMGQ4NTgwMy0zOGEwLTQyYjMtODA2ZS03YTRjZjhlMTk2ZWU' \
 -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '{
   "start_latitude": 37.7752278,
   "start_longitude": -122.4197513,
   "end_latitude": 37.7773228,
   "end_longitude": -122.4272052
 }' "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/estimate?scope=request
```

- Response

> {"code":"unauthorized","message":"This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: profile, request, request.delegate, request.delegate.tos_accept, surge_accept"}%

*While Below API are working Fine*

1. /products
2. /estimates/price
3. /estimates/time

Answer (score 0):

this is old API. New one looks like this.

> GET /v1.2/estimates/price